# Website is not changing browser Tab?

Tags: html

I am trying to make my first website in html this is my code:

```
<html>
<title>website</title>
<h1>hi.</h1>
</html>
```

help please

Comment: browser tab? whats not changing? and when do you want it to change?

Comment: where is head and body tag??

Comment: @Jalpesh why do you need the head and body tag?

Comment: @GowthamShiva its html format

Comment: modern browsers dont need those. just the title tags will be enough

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ThahmSO.png — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GowthamShiva — "modern"? No browser needs them. The tags have been optional since there was an HTML specification.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

place title tag in your `<head>`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>website</title>
</head>
<h1>hi.</h1>
</html>
```

hope that helps

Comment: did you try removing the `head` ?

Comment: That works. thank you

Comment: @GowthamShiva if you remove head than its not valid html

Comment: wrong code cause body tag missing.

Comment: The title element already is in the head. The start and end *tags* for the head and body elements are optional. Leaving them out is perfectly valid.